# Evaluating a sequence given a recurrent relation for consecutive values

Tags: calculus, functions

Let's say that $f$ is defined as a function on the set of integers such that $f(1) = 5$ and $f(x+1) = 2f(x) + 1$, how do I find $f(x)$ in general so I will be able to evaluate operations such as $f(3) - f(0)$ ?

Comment: Well, you know what $f(1)$ is, and you have your functional relation. Can you use that to find $f(2)$?

Comment: Write $f(x) = g(x) + C$ and choose the better $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me walk you through it. Start by applying the definition a few times, for $x=1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$:
$$\mbox{for } x=1: \quad f(2) = 2f(1) + 1 = 2 \cdot 5 + 1$$
$$\mbox{for } x=2: \quad f(3) = 2f(2) + 1 = 2 \left[ 2 \cdot 5 + 1 \right] + 1 = 2^2\cdot 5 + 2 +1$$
$$\mbox{for } x=3: \quad f(4) = 2f(3) + 1 = 2 \left[ 2^2\cdot 5 + 2 + 1 \right] + 1= 2^3\cdot 5 + 2^2 +2 + 1$$
$$\mbox{for } x=4: \quad f(5) = 2f(4) + 1 = 2 \left[ 2^3\cdot 5 + 2^2 +2 + 1 \right] + 1 = 2^4\cdot 5 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2 + 1$$
Perhaps you start seeing a pattern, which leads you to guess that
$$f(n+1) = 2^n\cdot 5 + 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \ldots + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 2^n\cdot 5 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$$
This is the expression suggested by Fred. As Arthur points out, you may now prove that this is correct for any $k \ge 1$ using mathematical induction. (For a quick-and-dirty argument, you may plug in the expression in the original formula and check out that it holds true.)

Incidentally, given that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = 2^n - 1$$
the expression derived by Fred may be rewritten as
$$f(n+1) = 2^n\cdot 5 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = 2^n\cdot 5 + 2^n - 1 = 2^n\cdot 6 - 1$$
as recommended by Arthur.

Finally, using the expression 
$$f(3) - f(0) = 23-2=21$$

Answer (score 1):

Show by induction: if $n \ge 1$ then

$f(n+1)=2^n*5+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k$

Comment: Why not $2^n\cdot 6 - 1$? Seems easier. Also, to the untrained eye, this looks like some expression you just pulled out of a hat (as does my expression, for that matter). To me, finding expressions is always a lot more difficult than testing them. Perhaps you should add a paragraph or two about how you found it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then it is a difference equation: $a_{n+1}=2a_n+1,a_1=5$, whose solution is:
$$a_n=3\cdot2^n-1=f(n).$$
Hence:
$$f(3)-f(0)=23-2=21.$$